# config.action_mailer.asset_host not serving images from cloud front CDN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-cloudfront, actionmailer

I have a CloudFront CDN serving my rails assets. When viewing source of assets served through a web browser it points to my CDN properly. However, Action Mailer is not using this path when serving its assets.

Why might this be?

Here is my environments/production.rb file:

```
 config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      :port => 587,
      :user_name => Figaro.env.smtp_username, #Your SMTP user
      :password => Figaro.env.smtp_password, #Your SMTP password
      :authentication => :login,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  config.action_controller.asset_host = Figaro.env.cloudfront_endpoint
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = Figaro.env.cloudfront_endpoint
```

Comment: What path is it using in your email?

Comment: Why do you have `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost' }` in your production config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not setting the correct value for `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`.

[This is what the docs says:](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views)

> Unlike controllers, the mailer instance doesn't have any context about the incoming request so you'll need to provide the `:host` parameter yourself.
>
> As the `:host` usually is consistent across the application you can configure it globally in `config/application.rb`

it should be:

```rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: Figaro.env.cloudfront_endpoint }
```

Note: make sure you are using `image_url` instead of `image_path` in your mail views/templates

Comment: I was overriding the host locally on my image_url tag. Your answer led me to this conclusion.

Comment: also pay attention to `config/application.yml` if exist